# What are the bestway to optimize bunyan logger in node.js production environment?

Tags: node.js, logging, bunyan

We are using bunyan logger to log messages in Node.js v4.2.4 environment. In production we use "error" log levels only. Below is an example of using logger in code.

```
logger.error("Error getting database connection, %s", err);
```

Here the "err" is the error object returned from module.

What I am curious about is that whether this is correct way of handling errors and logging them ?

What are the other optimizations suggesting when using bunyan as logger in production ?